# Regex leading space/add trailing space before/to punctuation

Tags: regex

To better clean my forum message corpus, I would like to remove the leading spaces *before* punctuation and add one *after* if needed, using two regular expressions. The latter was no problem (`(?<=[.,!?()])(?! )`) but I've some problem with the first at least.

I used this expression: `\s([?.!,;:"](?:\s|$))`

But it's by far not flexible enough:

- It matches even if there's already a space(or more) before the punctuation character
- It doesn't match if there's not a space after the punctuation character
- It doesn't match any unlisted punctuation character (but I guess I can use `[:punct:]` for that, at the end of the day)

Finally, both matches the decimal points (while they should not)

How can I eventually rewrite the expression to meet my needs?

Example Strings and expected output

```
This is the end .Hello world! # This is the end. Hello world! (remove the leading, add the trailing)
This is the end, Hello world! # This is the end, Hello world! (ok!)
This is the end . Hello world! # This is the end. Hello world! (remove the leading, ok the trailing)
This is a .15mm tube # This is a .15 mm tube (ok since it's a decimal point)
```

Comment: example would be better.

Comment: are you trying to match to match the strings or remove the spaces?

Comment: @AvinashRaj I added some examples and a better clarification of (both) my needs :)

Comment: could you post the expected output also?

Comment: @AvinashRaj ok, done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\p{P}` to match all the punctuations. Use `\h*` instead of `\s*` because `\s` would match newline characters also.

```
(?<!\d)\h*(\p{P}+)\h*(?!\d)
```

Replace the matched strings by `\1<space>`

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kP4pZ2/23)

```
> x <- c('This is the end .Stuff', 'This is the end, Stuff', 'This is the end . Stuff', 'This is a .15mm tube')
> gsub("(?<!\\d)\\h*(\\p{P}+)\\h*(?!\\d)", "\\1 ", x, perl=T)
[1] "This is the end. Stuff" "This is the end, Stuff" "This is the end. Stuff"
[4] "This is a .15mm tube"
```

Comment: very elegant, working smoothly and it's *almost* perfect! The only glitches are the open parhentesis (which in western languages has a backwarded behaviour - it stitch to the trailing word, not the preceeding) and the hypen (which should not match if intra word for example "bull-head"). Aside that, it's perfect!

Comment: This solved very smoothly the hypen issue (whoa, this regex far beyond my understanding capabilities. The last glitch before perfection is the open parhentesis behaviour (which link to the following word rather than the preceding)

Comment: Some punctuation characters must stitch to the following word, not the preceding. Your regex indisrciminately link the punctuation to the preceding word. After having applied your regex for example:

- The show( must go on) ---> Should be "The show (must go on)"
- The ork said to the princess:" Hello world!" ----> Should be The ork said to the princess: "Hello world!"
- Don' t be afraid ----> Should be "Don't be afraid" (this is probably the only exception: the elision character stitch two words together)

Coming in mind: ('"@...

Comment: Guess so. I tried to grammatically clean the text using only one regex....but I'm afraid it's not worth the pain. Tnx allot for your great help! This solved me 99.9999999% of my issue!

Answer (score 1):

Here's an expression that detects the substrings that need to be replaced:

```
\s*\.\s*(?!\d)
```

You need to replace these by: `.` (a dot and a space)

Here's a demo link of how this works: http://regex101.com/r/zB2bY3/1

Explanation of the regex:

- `\s*`  - matches whitespace, any number of chars (0 - unbounded)
- `\.`  - matches a dot
- `\s*` - same as above
- `(?!\d)` - negative lookahead. It means that the string, in order to be matched, must not be followed by a digit (this handles your last test case).

Comment: tnx @w0lf, it almost works. But the substitution is only for a defined character (the dot) while I need to match the whole class [:punct:]. Aside that, if there're several consecutive punctuation characters. For example "Once upon a time..." or "(as I said before!)